# PreparedStatement.addBatch in java has any restrictions?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to optimize the process of inserting a large number of results to a remote mySQL database. I'm using simple jdbc for that.

Currently I'm replacing exiting statements with PreparedStatement and execute methods with addBatch/executeBatch methods. Does anyone know which are the limits of a batch execution? How many batches can I add before execution to make sure the process doesn't fail? The queries are not special queries, they don't have blobs or other large fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@BalusC hit the nail on the head.  If you're using MySQL, use the latest driver add **rewriteBatchedStatements=true** to your connection string to make statement.addBatch() actually create batch inserts.

Nice presentation on MySQL JDBC performance:
http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/21/Connector_J%20Performance%20Gems%20Presentation.pdf